# REACT JS How can I display my fetched API data from onClick?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner and I could fetch and display API data object with map() function. Now I am trying to create a global fetch button and call the data with onClick that I fetched. When I check onClick with console.log, it works, but for some reason I can't display it in browser and it gives me no error.

**App component**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import Style from "./style.css"

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [myFilter, setFilter] = useState("chicken");

const recipeApi = {/*recipe api address*/}



const fetchData  = () => {
  fetch(recipeApi)
  .then(res => res.json()) 
  .then(result => setData(result.hits))
  .catch(err => console.log("error"))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [myFilter])


const searching = event => {
setSearch(event.target.value)
}



const mySearch = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setFilter(search);
  setSearch("");
}

function deleteHandler(index){
  setData(
      data.filter((element, filterIndex) => index !== filterIndex)
  )
}



console.log(fetchData)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button  type="submit" onClick = {fetchData}>fetch</button>
      <form  onSubmit = {mySearch} className = "search-form">
        <input className = "search-bar" value = {search} onChange = {searching} />
        <button className ="search-button" type="submit">search</button>
      </form>

      <button  type="submit" onClick = {fetchData}>search</button>   {/*here I call my fetched data */}

      <div className = "recipes"
         {data.map((element, index)=>(
            <Recipe
              onDelete={deleteHandler}
              title = {element.recipe.label} 
              image = {element.recipe.image}
              name = {element.recipe.source}
              index={index}
              key = {index} 
              calories = {element.recipe.calories}  
              ingredientLines = {element.recipe.ingredientLines[0]}
            />
          ))
         }  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**child component**

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./recipe.module.css"


export default function Recipe({title, image, name, calories, index, onDelete,refetch, ingredientLines}){
   return (

        <div className = {style.recipe}>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{name}</p>
            <p>Calories: {calories}</p>
            <p>Ingredients: {ingredientLines}</p>
            <img className = {style.image} src = {image} alt="" />
            <button  type="button"  onClick={() => onDelete(index)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you log data?

Comment: Change `console.log(fetchData)` to `console.log(data)` to see if it looks right.

Comment: @HMR I tried with data instead of fetchdata, it gives an error

Comment: @twharmonI tried with data instead of fetchdata, it gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `index` as the `key`. It might not update correctly.

```
<Recipe
    // some props ommitted
    key={JSON.stringify(element)}

    // if element has an id:
    // key={element.id}  
/>
```